# Pi Music box stream to DNLA device

Tags: output, mopidy

I downloaded Pi music box and I've got it setup and running (which is all good) so now I can use my phone/pc to connect to the Raspberry pi. But, now i want to connect the raspberry pi to my DNLA/airplay device. The device i have is a Airplay/DNLA amp. So my question is how can i make the Raspberry pi play music through my airplay/DLNA amp.

Thanks

~Neamus

Comment: This is dependent on the operating system, but (99.9% sure) all linux flavours including Raspbian have DNLA clients and servers in their repositories.

Comment: Did you look through the [Pi Music FAQs](http://docs.pimusicbox.com/en/latest/faq/) ... is this the question and answer: *Can Pi Musicbox stream to my Airplay device? ... No, this functionality is not supported.*

Comment: I read the faqs but I saw some option for dlna and I think there's another way to do the thing I want

Comment: I don't know... I downloaded the image file from their [github page](https://github.com/pimusicbox/pimusicbox/releases/tag/v0.7.0RC6) ... extracted the image file ... mounted the root partition and looked through the repo listing... It seems this project uses "Wheezy" as its base distro.  That's two versions ago, nearly three.  I'm not sure I would choose to utilize this project, as its update cycle seems non existent. Perhaps something like [libreelec](https://libreelec.tv/downloads/) will suit your needs better.